# Sharepoint Online: Retrieving PersonalURL for a user through the REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, user-profile, azure

I am looking for a way to the retrieve the following information for a user

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles.personproperties.aspx

Especially

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.personproperties.personalurl.aspx

through the REST API for Sharepoint Online (Office 365 subscription).

Can I get this info through the APIs? I am polling users through Graph API and I need this information against the users I get (but since Azure doesn't provide this, I am stuck)

I am aware of the User Profile API

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx#bk_PeopleManagerGetPropertiesFor

The  mentioned in the docs is an unknown in my case. I can't use the discovery service as well.

My understanding is that I could just use

```
https://<tenantName>-my.sharepoint.com
```

as a host (site URL) to use the User Profile API endpoints. Is this correct?

PS: We are using Client Credentials Flow to obtain the access token (i.e, no user context associated with the token)
Moreover, I have gone through CSOM and Powershell options, so I am aware of those. I am interested in the API endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this REST endpoint:

```
https://<server>/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getPropertiesFor(@v)?@v='domain\LoginName'
```

This retrieves all profile information for the given `LoginName`. You can select the property **PersonalUrl** by adding `$select = PersonalUrl`

For more information see the [User profiles REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to get this <serverURL> you have mentioned, the problem is that I fetch users through Azure AD(Graph) and there is no field that tells me the OneDrive Url for a user. So, I need to find out an API endpoint which could tell me that, i.e, for a user I need to know the personal site URL.

Comment: Wouldn't the discovery endpoint get you that, then in turn be able to use the above?

Comment: Try the following using the graph API: https://graph.windows.net/graphdir1.onmicrosoft.com/tenantDetails you can test this url here: https://graphexplorer2.cloudapp.net/Home/Index/DemoCompany

Comment: The Site URL is an unknown in my case and I can't use the Discovery service either. Can I just use https://<tenantName>-my.sharepoint.com?